# Disposing a Page causes a warning. Is this an issue?

Tags: c#, .net-core, puppeteer-sharp

I have the following code that creates, then closes a Chrome page via PuppeteerSharp:

```
var options = new LaunchOptions() {Headless = true, Args = new[] { "--disable-web-security" }};

Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options, factory);
Page page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.CloseAsync();
page.Dispose();
```

The last statement (page.Dispose) causes to write out the following warning:

> PuppeteerSharp.Page:Warning: Protocol error: Connection closed. Most likely the page has been closed.

I have the following questions:

1. Is this a problem?  Can I ignore this warning?
2. Do I need to `.Dispose` of the page after I close it?

Comment: 1) no,yes, 2) no   it would run faster

Comment: I recommend you using the `using` style, like here https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/samples/get-all-links/Program.cs#L16

Comment: @hardkoded This is a redacted piece of code.  The page gets instantiated elsewhere and is passed around.  Later in the life cycle, I need to close it in another method.  Therefore I have to call .CloseAsync.  I was just wondering whether or not I need to call .Dispose after (and if I do whether the warning presents a problem).

Comment: You don't need to call Dispose. It's just a fire and forget call to CloseAsync https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp/Page.cs#L2143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call Dispose if you call `CloseAsync`. Dispose is just a fire and forget call to CloseAsync. [See](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp/Page.cs#L2143).